# I need help fixing (Printing correct information) a simple app where a player attacks a boss with a random generator

Tags: java

I made this simple app where a player attacks a boss and the player has to tries to defeat the boss. What I am having trouble with is having my small java app to print after the boss has been defeated. My bosses' health is 5 and I have a random dice generator that ranges 1 - 6. When the player rolls "5" or a "6" on the first attack, I want the program to end. Another thing is that my program prints out I have defeated the boss even though the player has not dealt 5 or 6 of damage. I think it might be because of the for loop but I'm not sure.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Hey{
    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner attack = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random dice = new Random();

        String hits;
        int hitss,total = 0;

        System.out.println("Time to attack the boss!");
        System.out.println("Press letter 'A' to attack!");
        hits = attack.next();
        hitss = 1+dice.nextInt(6);

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

        if(hits.equals ("a")){

            System.out.println("You have hit a " + hitss);
            total += hitss;
        }
        if(total >= 5){
            System.out.println("Well done, You have defeated the boss!");

        }
        else if(total < 5){
            total = 5 - total;
             System.out.println("You need " + total + " more hits to defeat the boss!");

        }

        else
        {
             System.out.println("Sorry, you did not defeat the boss");
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
You have hit a 2
You need 3 more hits to defeat the boss!
You have hit a 2
Well done, You have defeated the boss!
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the scanner.

Your test for not defeating the boss has to be outside the for loop.

You needed a different variable (more) to see what hits were left.

You needed to break out of the for loop if you won on the first roll.

Here's your code with my changes

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Hey {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner attack = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random dice = new Random();

        String hits;
        int hitss, total = 0;

        System.out.println("Time to attack the boss!");
        System.out.println("Press letter 'A' to attack!");
        hits = attack.next();
        hitss = 1 + dice.nextInt(6);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (hits.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("You have hit a " + hitss);
                total += hitss;
            }
            if (total >= 5) {
                System.out.println("Well done, You have defeated the boss!");
                break;
            } else {
                int more = 5 - total;
                System.out.println("You need " + more
                        + " more hits to defeat the boss!");

            }

        }
        if (total < 5) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you did not defeat the boss");
        }
        attack.close();
    }
}
```